# How to load url from settings.bundle in xCode 4.2

Tags: xcode, settings.bundle

I'm try to programming in xCode, but it is new for me. I neeed to write simple webview-application for ios 5. My App must load url, that defined in settings every time, when opened. I create xCode project and add settings.bundle to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>http://192.168.0.4/portal.aspx</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>serverName</string>
            <key>KeyboardType</key>
            <string>Alphabet</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Server</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My code:

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];   

    server = [defaults objectForKey:@"serverName"];    
    if(server==nil)
        server=@"http://google.com";    

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [proView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: server]]];
    proView.scalesPageToFit= YES;
}
```

but my app always starts google page. Why server is nil? And server must have default value? what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you have to set the defaults manually, or else they are null. Try this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *server = [defaults objectForKey:@"serverName"];
NSLog(@"%@", server); // <-- should print null

//If the default value is null, set a value
if(server==nil) {
[defaults setObject:@"http://192.168.0.4/portal.aspx" forKey:@"serverName"];
//change your string to reflect the changes.
server = [defaults ObjectForKey:@"serverName"];
NSLog(@"%@", server); // <-- should print your URL
}

[defaults synchronize]; //Saves defaults.

[super viewDidLoad];

[proView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: server]]];
proView.scalesPageToFit= YES;

}
```